# Manually modify Code API pages?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought that there would be cases where sharing internal design docs (UML diagrams etc.) is beneficial to the future developers (or even to users?). But wiki pages (`ros.org/wiki/$TOOL_HOME$`) might be better saved for how-to-use explanation rather than internal implementation description. Code API pages (`ros.org/doc/groovy/api/$TOOL_HOME$/html`) seem perfect place, but is there a way to manually update API pages (via web browser like wiki)? I've seen [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/50622/are-there-ros-api-documents-published-and-where/) that says API pages are autogenerated from code documents but haven't found anything that answers my question. Being able to modify the page layout helps particularlly when I want to paste images.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54407/manually-modify-code-api-pages?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The API documentation comes from doxygen, sphinx or epydoc inside each package. See the [rosdoc_lite](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdoc_lite) documentation for how to enable each of these documentation methods.  The default is mainpage.dox which is generated by ros_create_pkg.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0